# Consume LWC's getListUi wire in Aura component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I want to grab list views in Aura by sobjectType and list view name. I already made a component that does a request, but fail to expose the data to Aura. Attribute change handler never fires and upon button click return default value.

Consumer code:

```
<aura:attribute name="listView" type="Object" access="private" default="{}"/>
<aura:attribute name="selectedView" type="Object" access="private"/>
<lightning:button label="what" onclick="{!c.what}"/>
<c:wireListView
        listViewApiName="{!v.selectedView.NamespacePrefix+'__'+v.selectedView.DeveloperName}"
        objectApiName="{!v.selectedObject}"
        listView="{!v.listView}"/>
```

wireListView markup:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="WireListView" icon-name="custom:custom67">
        <template if:true={listView.data}>
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <template for:each={contacts} for:item="contact">
                    <p key={contact.fields.Id.value}>
                        {contact.fields.Name.value}
                    </p>
                </template>
            </div>
        </template>
        view name {listViewApiName}
        sobject name {objectApiName}
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

(Note that markup will be gone in future, I need a modular, headless component)

wireListView code:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
import { getListUi } from 'lightning/uiListApi';

export default class WireListView extends LightningElement {
    @api objectApiName;
    @api listViewApiName;
    @api listView;
    @wire(getListUi, {
            objectApiName: '$objectApiName',
            listViewApiName: '$listViewApiName'
        })
    listView
    get contacts() {
        return this.listView.data.records.records;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is add below to wireListView:

```
@api get result(){
    return this.listView;
}
```

then consume as following:

```
<c:wireListView
        listViewApiName="{!v.selectedView.NamespacePrefix+'__'+v.selectedView.DeveloperName}"
        objectApiName="{!v.selectedObject}"
        result="{!v.listView}"/>
```